# Python UserList module

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python. I'm thinking to use a class named Ulist to override the **add**, append, and extend methods, so that duplicate values will not be added to the list by any of these operations. Below is my code. But the problem is that when i tried to print out mylist, the result is an empty list. Can you help let me know which part of my code is wrong? Thanks!

```
class Ulist(UserList):
    def __init__(self, data):
        UserList.__init__(self)
        self.list = data

    def __add__(self, newdata):
        for i in newdata:
            if i in self.list:
                print (i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.list += [i]
        return self.list

    def append(self,newdata):
        for i in newdata:
            if i in self.list:
                 print (i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.list.append(i)
        return self.list

    def extend(self,newdata):
         for i in newdata:
            if i in self.list:
                  print (i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.list.extend(i)
         return self.list

mylist = Ulist([1,2,3])

mylist.__add__([1,2])
print (mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your self.list -> self.data

```
class Ulist(UserList):
    def __init__(self, data):
        UserList.__init__(self)
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, newdata):
        for i in newdata:
            if i in self.data:
                print (i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.data += [i]
        return self.data

    def append(self, newdata):
        for i in newdata:
            if i in self.data:
                 print (i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.data.append(i)
        return self.data

    def extend(self, newdata):
         for i in newdata:
            if i in self.data:
                  print (i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.data.extend(i)
         return self.data

mylist = Ulist([1,2,3])

mylist.__add__([1,2])
print (mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UserList` doesn't store it's data as `self.list` it stores itself as `self.data`:

```
from collections import UserList
class Ulist(UserList):
    def __init__(self, data):
        UserList.__init__(self)
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, newdata):
        for i in newdata:
            if i in self.data:
                print(i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.data += [i]
        return self.data

    def append(self, newdata):
        for i in newdata:
            if i in self.data:
                 print(i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.data.append(i)
        return self.data

    def extend(self, newdata):
         for i in newdata:
            if i in self.data:
                  print(i, "not be added to the list")
            else:
                self.data.extend(i)
         return self.data


mylist = Ulist([1, 2, 3])

mylist.__add__([1, 2])
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
1 not be added to the list
2 not be added to the list
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!